# Is there a verb for people of the same sex marrying in latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request, word-choice

As far as I know there are two words in Latin that indicate two people marrying

1. *nubere*
   This means to veil oneself for marriage. It thus has to be said by a female member and it is implied that this is said to a man. (woman-man marriage)
2. *duco uxorem*
   This means to take a woman as your wife, therefore it requires the presence of a female in the marriage and the other side is implied to be a man. (man-woman marriage)

The two of these words could, as far as I know in theory also be used to be a woman-woman marriage but I wonder whether the Latin language has a word that more clearly means woman-woman marriage and whether it has a word for man-man marriage at all.

It might also be possible that such a word was added to the Latin language after the classical era in which case I would like to know in which era it was added.

As an example sentence: "the man married his boyfriend."

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : there are no such words. However, as Joonas suggests, there are ways of getting round this if you want to express same-sex ideas in Latin.

I've never come across anything specific for woman-woman or man-man marriages (or marrying) in the language but, if there lies behind your question a need to express these in Latin, it's by no means impossible.

To begin with, there is the neutral phrase, offered by Joonas, *in matrimonium ducere*, which conventionally suggests a man taking a woman to wife but might, in the right context, be used in the ways that your are looking for.

Next, there is the useful word *coniu(n)x*, which means 'spouse', usually of a wife but also of a man. A married couple can be described as *coniuges* — 'conjoined', (if you like, in marriage) in a physical union, *coniugium* — where, again, the context could suggest a same-sex marriage [note here that *connubium* is a separate, legal term for wedlock or marriage]. We should also consider that the Romans 'married' in various ways.

The way of the old Republic, and especially of the patricians and otherwise ennobled families, was *confarreatio*, a very solemn and serious religious affair, strongly binding and usually involving settlements of one kind or another (think of Julius Caesar giving his daughter in marriage to Pompey, or Octavian his sister to Antony), including money or property. Marriage between plebeians was called *coemptio* and did not involve the same rites as *confarreatio*, but mimicked a sale and was solemnised before at least five witnesses ( there was even a *libripens* to simulate the weighing-out of money). But a possible key to the usage you are looking for is that ,in all kinds of marriage, there was a question to the bride, and her response was *Ubi tu Gaius, ego Gaia* : this is straightforwardly adaptable to a same-gender couple.

Classical literature refers us to all kinds of sexual activity. Some of it can be a bit puritanical, but aside from that there are allegations of sexual 'misbehaviour' which are mainly in the nature of lampoon of the subjects, rather than criticism of the act (Catullus has particularly good examples). In Latin, as far as I know, they are all of males (and they do include pederasty) : I know of nothing which has words specially for female-female sexual activity, though there are a some which *might* be used.

I appreciate, of course, that none of this answers your query as such, but as a bit of background it should, I hope, enable you to deal with it confidently.

Answer (score 1):

Pitkäranta's dictionary (Finnish–Latin–Finnish) gives three translations for "get married" in two categories.
Marrying a woman can be expressed by *uxorem ducere* or *in matrimonium ducere*, both with accusative.
Marrying a man can be expressed by *nubere* with dative.

These translations are probably offered from a heteronormative point of view, but they can be adapted to new uses.
The expressions *nubere alicui* and *aliquem in matrimonium ducere* are syntactically gender neutral, but *nubere* has unwanted connotations as my mention.
Leading someone to matrimony, *aliquem in matrimonium ducere*, is a good neutral option.

Depending on how you want to structure things, one possibility is ***aliquem maritum ducere***.
This "leading someone to become his husband" is an obvious adaptation of the well known phrase, and the change makes it clear that something is not quite like in the Roman concept(s) of marriage.
This is what I would choose for your example.

See [this question for Latin expressions for "boyfriend" or "girlfriend"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7630/79).

Using just *amatus*, I end up with this example:

> He married his boyfriend.
>   *Ille amatum suum duxit maritum.*

Comment: Since *puer* was regularly used to mean servant, and since Romans not infrequently took sexual liberties with their servants, I don't think that last sentence quite conveys what you want.  Of course, that's the danger with all of this--how can you say it in a way that doesn't sound like Martial quipped it first?

Comment: @CMonsour Indeed, I had forgotten to update this answer after the spin-off question. I added a link there and updated my suggestion on that part. It should work better now, and the details of that choice of words can be discussed in the linked question. I only wanted to pick a single sample here to show how marrying would work.

Comment: I was wondering to what extent "_aliquem in matrimonium ducere_ is a good neutral option". You point out that _nubere_ has "unwanted connotations". Well, one could also claim that the use of the verb _ducere_ 'to lead' has "unwanted connotations" too... By the way, your last example is ambiguous, isn't it? The verb _duxit_ could also be interpreted as "he **considered** his boyfriend as his husband".  Such an ambiguity disappears if one uses a directional expression like _in matrimonium_.