# What is a boyfriend or a girlfriend in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin

When answering [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7611/79), it occurred to me that I don't know what to call a "boyfriend" or a "girlfriend" in Latin.
What would be good words?

I assume that the same solution will work for both with obvious modifications, but I will be happy to be proven wrong as always.
There might not be a perfect fit but several options for different uses.
Therefore I request that if you suggest a translation or several, please also describe what good and bad aspects it has as a translation.
That way anyone stumbling on this question can find the answer that fits their particular case best.

Notice that I'm not looking for a name to call a loved one (as in "veni huc, mel meum!"), but a word for the status.
I'm looking for something that would work in "do you have a boyfriend?" and "here's my girlfriend" and similar.
These refer to somewhat informal romantic relationships, so engagement and marriage should be kept out of the vocabulary here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discussed this with some colleagues this week, and here is a commented list of suggestions in rough order of personal preference:

- ***amatus/amata***:
  Quite literally "the loved one".
  One can love another person in a number of ways, so it's not clear that it would refer to boyfriend instead of an idol or some other important person.
  However, in proper context and combined with *meus/mea* this should be clear enough.
- ***dilectus/dilecta***:
  Essentially a synonym of the previous one.
- ***amicus/amica***:
  Quite literally "friend".
  It depends on context whether it's clear enough that it's more than just friendship.
  For some reason I have the impression that the Latin *amicus/amica* has more romantic connotations than the English "friend".
- ***amiculus/amicula***:
  In some contexts the diminutive might bring extra familiarity to the word.
  Again, there is a risk of misinterpretation, but I might find myself using this word especially in early stages of dating.
  This construction is quite similar to the French *petit ami* or *petite amie*.
- ***amator/amatrix***:
  This word makes it abundantly clear that it's not mere friendship, but I feel that it gives quite a lot of emphasis on the physical side of things.
  If the relationship is more romantic than sexual (or you want to portray it in such light), I would use another word.
- ***puer/puella***:
  Especially with *meus/mea*, this could be understood correctly.
  But it sounds a little belittling to me, and the word can also be used for slaves or servants.
  This is a valid alternative for purposes of variation, but I wouldn't introduce anyone as someone's *puer/puella*.

Answer (score 4):

***sponsus/sponsa*** are often translated just as "groom/bride" - and this meaning is reflected by the Italian *sposo/sposa* as well as the English "spouse"-  but in fact, they were also used by the Romans to address a *fiancé/fiancée*. After all, *sponsus,a,um* is the past participle of *spondeo*, "to promise", and engagement was pretty serious business in Ancient Rome.

On the other hand, *amicus/amica* could be used to indicate a paramour.

The following passage from Seneca the Elder, *Controversiae* is insightful for both expressions:

> Hunc sensum Vibius Rufus subtiliter dixit: volo tibi malam gratiam cum sponso tuo facere: habet amicam.

Comment: IIRC, in a book I no longer have access to, on Latin forms of address, *domine /domina* were also used to address a beloved, though possibly not to *refer* to them.

Comment: @TheHonRose: Interesting! If you happen to stumble again on that book or something else confirming it, make sure to post an answer!

Comment: This is a link to the book on Google Books, might be searchable? https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vakSDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: ªTheHonRose: Weren´´t "Domine/ Domina" forms of address to high-ranking people? A slave would address his master as  "Domine", the "Imperatrix", "Domina"--"Lady"?

Answer (score 2):

Orberg, in Familia Latina, uses amica in the sense of girlfriend or fiancee.

Answer (score 1):

In my old Latin text book, the word for Lover was *amans, amantis* (M/F). *Amicus, Amica* usually mean just friend.